# How to display an image in a expo local notification

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-notifications

To give more clarity on the issue, i am developing this for IOS using expo notifications and expo sdk44 in my current project.

I have a couple of questions which i failed to find the answer to in their official documentation.

Is it possible to display images in a local notification while using expo's `expo-notification` library?

Is it possible to send "data-only" messages to Apple devices using expo push notification service?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`expo-notifications` has limited features and not currently support a custom image in the notification.

In case you need a native-like notification experience, you should opt for https://notifee.app/.